# How to delete child table from value?

Tags: sql

I have one TableA, with 2 SmallTableA linked with TableA. They both have a foreign key to TableA.
So if my Table A is:

```
TableA
------
idA
Name
```

My ChildTables are:

```
ChildTableA
-----------
IdChildTable
numA
name
```

I want to delete all the records from my 2 SmallTableA corresponding to the rows from TableA `where TableA.name = @name`.

I tried it this way :

```
DELETE FROM ChildTableA1
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT ChildTableA1.*
          FROM ChildTableA1 INNER JOIN TableA ON ChildTableA.numA = TableA.idA
          WHERE (TableA.name = @name))
```

The problem is that it removes all of the rows from ChildTable1, like if I do:

```
Delete * from ChildTableA1.
```

Is there a way to delete from ChildTableA1 and ChildTableA2 in one time, but only for the rows matching the criteria?

Comment: You really need to clarify structure of "from ChildTableA1 and ChildTableA1" (plus both names looks the same to me, not sure what you mean).

Comment: This really has nothing to do with C# or Visual Studio, but mentioning the database type might be of use

Answer (score 0):

Your `DELETE` will indeed delete everything, since the query means "delete row from this table if this exists" and since the `EXISTS` is true, all rows are deleted. You need to give the `WHERE` condition to the actual `DELETE`

```
DELETE FROM ChildTableA1
  WHERE numA IN (SELECT idA FROM TableA
    WHERE TableA.name = @name);
```

This way each row is checked for matching row in TableA.

If you want to delete from two tables at once, it is not possible, unless they have a foreign key between them and `CASCADE DELETE` set for the constraint. If there is a `CASCADE DELETE` present for the linked table, just doing

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE name = @name;
```

will also cause the deletion of the referencing rows in the other tables.